# Nav Image on mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navbar

I have built this  [site](http://www.crossfitkimokeo.com/)When I'm viewing it on mobile I can see the Nav Bar image, But if I view the site on a phone I no longer can see the Nav Bar image. Here is the CSS.
Any help would be appreciated. 
background: url("/img/nav-bar/group35.png");
`.mobile-nav-logo {

```
font-size: 35px;
height: 50px;
width: 123px;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
left: 19px;
top: 9px;
cursor: pointer;
background-size: contain;
cursor: pointer;
```

}`

Comment: Where is it? Edit it again.

Comment: i couldn't add the background: `url("/img/nav-bar/group35.png");` how wanted

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature, not a bug. The template you are using has a mobile menu that it switches to when the screen width goes below 1000px. You click on the little stack icon and it pulls up the menu.

Comment: Thanks nick but actually it was me not cleaning up my cache!

Answer (score 0):

It's because there is a media query that hides the nav to make it mobile friendly:

When the screen reaches 1000px the nav bar collapses.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px)
style.css?ver=1.0:1457
.nav-bar {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my problem was a caching issue. I changed the image to be a .svg. But chrome was caching the old image which didn't exist anymore.